# Property or method * is not defined. Error when render

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I'm new to Vue.js. The problem is that I cannot fill the table with the values of the JSON. The console shows:

> Property or method "tables" is not defined

And when I click the button, it says:

> Property or method "allRecords" is not defined

I don't know why. Could it be a problem in index.js or a problem in the code below?

Thanks

```
<template>
      <div >
        <input type='button' @click='allRecords()' value='Select All users'>
        <b-table striped hover responsive id="tabla_final" >
          <tr v-for='table in tables'>
                <td>{{ table.sum_real }}</td>
                <td>{{ table.sum_ppto }}</td>
                <td>{{ table.sum_real }}</td>
              </tr>
        </b-table>
    </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    import Vue from 'vue'
    const axios = require('axios')
    window.onLoad = function () {
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#tabla_final',
        data: {
          tables: ''
        },
        methods: {
          allRecords: function () {
            axios.get('http://localhost/Tribeca/api.php')
              .then(function (response) {
                app.tablas = response.data
                console.log(response.data)
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error)
              })
          }
        }
      })
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using `window.onLoad = function () { ...`, ? that seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a single-file Vue component, that means `vue-loader` is expecting the contents of the `<template>` tag to be the template definition of the component, and the contents of the `<script>` tag to export the configuration object used when instantiating the Vue instance.

Currently, your `<template>` contains a valid template definition, but your `<script>` doesn't export anything. So when the Vue instance gets instantiated based on the contents of this file, it doesn't know where to find the `tables` property that's being referenced in the template.

You appear to be trying to mount a Vue instance to an element within the template definition. But, you should just export your Vue instance configuration object instead:

```
<template>
  <div >
    <input type='button' @click='allRecords()' value='Select All users'>
    <b-table striped hover responsive id="tabla_final" >
      <tr v-for='table in tables'>
        <td>{{ table.sum_real }}</td>
        <td>{{ table.sum_ppto }}</td>
        <td>{{ table.sum_real }}</td>
      </tr>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
const axios = require('axios')

export default {
  data() {
    return { tables: '' }
  },
  methods: {
    allRecords: function () {
      let self = this;
      axios.get('http://localhost/Tribeca/api.php')
        .then(function (response) {
          self.tables = response.data
          console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

Note that you'll also need to make `data` a function which returns an object, and correctly reference the `tables` data property in the `then` callback of the `axios` call.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
app.tables = response.data
```

To

```
this.tables = response.data
```

Whenever you want to reference a property inside data –tables in this case–, use **this.nameOfProperty**.

Comment: idk why OP is creating a separate Vue instance set to `app`, but in this case, `this` would not reference the Vue instance, but the scope of the function in the `then` callback, so setting `this.tables` would not update the instance's `tables` data property. You'd need to reference `app.tables`. This also isn't what is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. He says he's new to Vue, so I think we are both right. He needs to export the component as you did in your answer and then he needs to actually update the `tables` property as I wrote. Cheers.